# I need to have a method run between periods of user interacction not sure how to do so

Tags: c#

I have a program, a rudimentary rpg of sorts, the player hits a button to attack then the computer needs to do so. I'm unable to get the ai components to work properly. If I try to call the method from the same button I use to have the player attack the attacks don't work.

So I'm trying to find another way to do this but I'm unsure of what to use. I was thinking maybe a while loop, but I know it will just hang there as soon as it runs. Also i need it to be running constantly in the background. I suppose I could do it in some other way than a loop but again am unsure of what to use. In the option of not using a loop I'm not sure of how to have the npc ai functions execute without having them attached to the button somehow.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is a game-developmepment site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Usually, games have following architecture: game loop (that can be either infinite loop (e.g., `while (true)`), or more acceptable way (speaking of C#, of course) to have game timer that will invoke callback in every predefined time interval (fps depends on this interval), call back itself should call two methods, one that updates game objects, simulates physics, handles user input, etc, and second, that will render game. Also keep in mind that some process may interrupt your timer, that will result late callback invocation so it's a good idea to calculate real elapsed time between...

Comment: but I'm just working inside windows forms. so I figured its not technically a game thing yet. I'll go check there though.

Edit: also I havent learned anything about timers yet but this may be a good time.

Comment: last and current invocations and pass it two both `Update` and `Draw`.

Comment: @AmazingMrBrock Also you might want to look at xna framework. Gives some good basics

Comment: @Leri I would but i figured I should learn how to program first. This is kind of a project I started as a way to learn. Made a dice roller and have been progressing it from a console program into a windows form program.

Comment: @AmazingMrBrock Take some good book in that case. You'll get faster results

Answer (score 0):

Numerous ways to do this with threads, but here's a [simple one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). Scroll down to examples.

Comment: thanks I haven't learned anything about threading yet but I knew it was a thing and I'll look into this.

Comment: This could and should be a comment. :)